# Guess the name of the city or country

Tags: riddle

It might be a simple riddle.

> I am a 9 letters country or city.
>
> First 5 letters are a religion name.
>
> 8th, 9th and 7th letters form a small insect name.
>
> 6th, 2nd, 9th, 4th, 1st and 5th letters spell a river name.

Who am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> Hindustan (AKA India)

First five letters are religion name

> Hindu

8,9,7 letters are a small insect name.

> Ant

6,2,9,4,1,5 letters are river name.

> Sindhu, a river

Comment: right answer... Wait...

Comment: I got it but you're very fast..

Comment: @Anjan Isn't it a region instead of a city/country?

Comment: @IAmInPLS India is also called as Hindustan. It is country only.

Comment: India also called Hindusatn and Bharat.

Answer (score 2):

The Answer is:

> Hindustan

The first Five letters are:

> Hindu

Letters 8,9,7 relating insects are:

> Ant

6,2,9,4,1,5 letters relating rivers are:

> Sindhu

Answer (score -1):

Well, this one was easy.

> Hindustan (India)

The first five letters are:

> Hindu

Letters 8,9,7 representing insect are:

> Ant

Letters 6,2,9,4,1,5 representing river are:

> Sindhu

Comment: You might want to say why this answer is the good one. Detail your answer.